# Как расшифровать строку правильно

Tags: java, android

Я вот не сильно разбираюсь в шифровании. Если у кого то есть предположения, как мне помочь, говорите)) .

У меня есть устройство, которое подключается к телефону и читает информацию с кредитной карты — `card reader` своего рода.

Так вот я получаю вот такой массив

```
44 55 66 77 00 00 21 37 af f9 67 f9 55 80 32 69 b8 d4 d1 39 62 9b c7 c2 1c 41 ae e9 16 64 39 c7 e6 e7 a6 c0 3d 2b e9 5e e2 71 3b e3 7a 05 bd 82 46 02 09 29 fe b7 5c 28 8d e6 6f a4 3d 72 4a 4c b2 d3 62 4e 2d 08 c7 0c f9 49 97 fe c3 0b b8 9a dd 56 f5 a2 3a 0f c6 f9 89 39 3a 1a 38 26 90 25 30 78 4a 81 6b 78 da 28 ad 41 da 48 4e 60 58 73 e5 c4 c1 45 af 35 1f 52 d7 74 f0 99 25 1f 01 05 31 30 30 30 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

который вот таким способом конвертирую с строку

```
String[] tmps = event.getValue().split(" ");
            StringBuffer sbf = new StringBuffer();
            for (String str : tmps) {
                sbf.append((char) Integer.parseInt(str, 16));
                sbf.append(" ");
            }
            final String data = sbf.toString().replaceAll(" ", "");
```

И в итоге получаю вот такое значение

```
DUfw����!7¯ùgùU2i¸ÔÑ9bÇÂA®éd9Çæç¦À=+é^âq;ãz½F   )þ·\(æo¤=rJL²ÓbN-ÇùIþÃ¸ÝVõ¢:Æù9:8&%0xJkxÚ(­AÚHN`XsåÄÁE¯5R×tð%1000����������������
```

У меня есть вот такая проверка

```
// plain text of card data
            if (data.toUpperCase().startsWith("B") && idx > 0 && data.indexOf("?") > 0) {
```

которая говорит о том, что можно получить чистые данные, если строка будет начинаться с `B` , в другом случае

```
// encryption data of card data
            else if (data.length() > 20 + 5 + 4) {
```

Это зашифрованые данные.

Так вот я не могу понять, как расшифровать их или как сделать так, чтоб они изначально не были зашифрованы.

Я пробовал в разных системах расшифровывать в 10, 2, 8 , но ничего не получилось.

Если что-то забыл, спрашивайте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже что `DUfw` он же `44 55 66 77` - это дескриптор протокола, а `1000` в конце терминатор протокола. Все что между ними какой-то шифрованный поток, который вы не дешифруете, иначе я начну сомневаться в интеллекте разработчиков протокола обмена данными с картой :)

Не мучайтесь.

Comment: если я правильно понял то это зашифрованая строка которую расшифровать не возможно будет, верно?

Comment: Дайте инфо что за карта и что за данные вы оттуда берете и в ходе чего? Транзакции купли-продажи, авторизации или что это. Побольше деталей

Comment: Ситуация такая у меня есть устройство которое подключается к телефону card reader и может читать карточки с этим устройством идет демо версия проекта с примером кода как использовать. Мне нужно разобраться как работает код и встроить эту имплементацию в свой проект который будет использовать эти данные по карте для оплаты комунальных услуг. Карта обычная кредитка, можно сказать, что это транзакция купли продажи. Продавец устройства сказал что оно читает данные и все работает, но я получаю их зашифрованные и не могу понять могу я это исправить или нет. Что скажите?

Comment: Я нашел ключ `E3 CB 50 99 5C E9 0E A2 06 7A C9 25 45 A5 B6 3A`  подскажите пожалуйста как его применить, чтоб расшифровать?

Comment: Его нужно применять к `hex` строке или уже к `String` который я получил в итоге ?

Comment: Чтобы дешифровать буфер вам нужно знать 4 вещи:

 1. Ключ (он у вас якобы есть)
 2. Алгоритм шифрования (DES/AES и проч.)
 3. [Алгоритм сцепления блоков](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC_%D1%81%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0) (ECB/CBC и т.д.)
 4. Алгоритм выравнивание блоков - [padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)) (PKCS7/ISO 10126) - у вас кстати похоже на *bit padding* :)

Comment: Судя по длине ключа и общим признакам у вас AES-256 с *bit padding* ну и обычно это режим CBC

Comment: В итоге техническая поддержка прислала мне код дешифрования. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

По-моему Ваш вопрос не имеет ответа, так как вполне возможно, что расшифровать данную строку невозможно. Если о типе шифрования нет никаких дополнительных данных, то ваш вопрос лишён смысла. Если система шифрования сделана качественно, то ваши преобразования в 2, 8, 10 СС, очевидно, ничего не дадут.

Comment: да я понимаю, что возможно мой вопрос не имеет смысла, поэтому вначале я сказал, что не сильно в этом разбираюсь и возможно, что то упустил